How to fetch Text column of PostgreSQL from Flink Table API
I am getting the following exception when trying to fetch a text column from a table in PostgreSQL. How to resolve it.
Table schema :

Snapshot of data :

Table resultTable = tenv.sqlQuery(
                "SELECT entity_id, CONVERT_FROM(LO_GET(event_payload::oid), 'UTF8') " +
                        "FROM event_log");

Exception stack trace
Caused by: org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered ":" at line 1, column 52.
Was expecting one of:
    "EXCEPT" ...

Dependencies
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Required for connecting to JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.2</version>
        </dependency>

UPDATE :
I tried changing the query but getting new exception
Table resultTable = tenv.sqlQuery(
                "SELECT entity_id, convert_from(lo_get(cast (event_payload as OID )), 'UTF8') " +
                        "FROM event_log");

Exception
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: SQL validation failed. From line 1, column 62 to line 1, column 64: Unknown identifier 'OID'
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.calcite.FlinkPlannerImpl.org$apache$flink$table$planner$calcite$FlinkPlannerImpl$$validate(FlinkPlannerImpl.scala:187)



HI. I suggest according to connector doc you should use flink-connector-jdbc version 3.1.2-1.17. Have you tried to select your column without any transformation ? What's you table looks like ?

@Niko
I updated my question with the schema. I updated the version but still getting same error.  It works fine without any transformation but since I need to fetch the text column as string, I need to add the transformation in query.

It seems to me CONVERT_FROM and LO_GET functions is postgre functions and I'm not sure you can use them in Flink SQL. You probably need to use Flink built-in functions or make an UDF. And if you trying to rename your column as OID it should be after function call like SELECT your_function(event_payload ) AS oid FROM ...

It seems to me CONVERT_FROM and LO_GET functions is postgre functions and I'm not sure you can use them in Flink SQL. Look for Flink built-in functions if you need to do any casts or transformations.
Your column having text type in postgre table so according to data-type-mapping it's equivalent to String type in Flink and you don't really need to transform it to string. Just select it.
SELECT event_payload FROM event_log

And if you trying to rename your column as OID should go after function call like:
SELECT some_function(event_payload) AS oid FROM event_log


The issue you encountering is related to the face that Flink not  directly  support Postgresql specific-function  and types , like  OID or  CONVERT_FROM ?
and here is two approaches for reference
1. create a view in database
you can create a view in postgresql  that  you can use all function you need , just take the eventual data ; view sql like following  code snippet , may be modify somewhere as you need;
CREATE VIEW event_log_view AS
SELECT entity_id, convert_from(lo_get(cast(event_payload as OID)), 'UTF8') as event_payload_text
FROM event_log;


and then  you can use native sql in flink smoothly
Table resultTable = tenv.sqlQuery("SELECT entity_id, event_payload_text FROM event_log_view");

2. perform conversion in java
I mean  you can hard code in java that perform conversion when dataset received
Table resultTable = tenv.sqlQuery("SELECT entity_id, event_payload FROM event_log");

resultTable.map(row -> {
    String entityId = row.getField("entity_id").toString();
    byte[] eventPayload = (byte[]) row.getField("event_payload");
    String eventPayloadText = new String(eventPayload, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // or perform OID-based conversion if needed
    return Row.of(entityId, eventPayloadText);
});



